# Mixed JOIN and COMMA table listing in FROM; meaning of listed items

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, left-join

Ok, I currently tasked with maintaining a legacy SQL Server 2005 database recently migrated to 2008 [R2] and there are some sprocs with something like the following:

```
SELECT 
   @val = c.TableVal
FROM
   dbo.TaqbleA a
   LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB b
       ON a.TableId = b.TableId
   ,dbo.TableC c
WHERE
  a.TableId = c.TableId
```

Fist off I know that the join conditions as seen with table A and B are the normal and how I'd rewrite this but I'm wondering if Table C is treated as a LEFT JOIN as it is listed after the LEFT JOIN or if it is treated as an INNER JOIN?  My gut says it is treated as an INNER JOIN, but I'm not certain. Which is it?

Furthermore, I know I'm not the only one who has ever seen something like this and it would be good to have this answer immortalized in the StackExchange...

Thanks.

Comment: looks like cartesian product to me

Comment: I dont understant "WHERE p.TableId = r.TableId" - cant see p or r as tables or aliases in the query

Comment: It's an `INNER JOIN`, since the filter (`WHERE`) is applied to the whole dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is effectively an `INNER JOIN` or `CROSS JOIN`; the comma has lower precedence than the explicit `JOIN`, so `FROM ... LEFT JOIN ... ON ..., ...` means `FROM (... LEFT JOIN ... ON ...), ...`, with the `LEFT JOIN` pertaining only to the first two tables.